# How can I mark a user as undesirable for me?

Tags: feature-request

That is if a user saves up, for example, 3 my dislikes under his posts, all his posts will be marked for me as undesirable.

Comment: What would this do, and why would this be useful?

Comment: This site is about questions and answers. It shouldn't matter who asks or answers them.

Comment: What exactly would a user be doing in order to earn such dislikes?

Comment: One of the reasons I see why this would not be a good idea, is because user's posts are either answers that help with a problem or question, and questions, which ask about something. Why would you not want to see people's problems, or solutions?

Comment: @Oded be on the wrong side on tabs vs. spaces, for example

Comment: The site dislikes a user when they post too many low-quality contributions. Other than that, I see no reason for so much hate.

Answer (score 9):

To answer the question as asked, no, that functionality does not exist. There is no way to do what your title asks how to do.

Since you tagged this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) rather than [support](/questions/tagged/support), it's possible you are asking to have this capability added. I don't support that, and rather doubt anybody will, since one of the stated design goals of this site is that we react to questions and answers, not to who asked or who answered. You should be able to get value from the site no matter who is creating the content.

To go further and ask the unasked equivalent of your question - *"What can I do about a user whose content I don't like? Why do I have to keep seeing that?"*, let me suggest selecting from among these options:

- if the user is a lazy writer, using text speak and mispunctuating, consider editing to make the post more pleasant for everyone. You can use suggested edits for this, which are an option for everyone regardless of rep.
- if the user has left blatantly offensive and rude content, whether a question, an answer, or a comment, flag it so that a moderator (or in some cases an automated system) can clean it up. You need to earn some rep to be able to flag, so if you don't have this capability yet, considering working towards it.
- if the question is poorly written and a waste of time, downvote it. With enough downvotes it will be removed from the front page and you're less likely to see it. Again, you need to meet a rep threshold to downvote, but it's worth working your way to that.
- if there is extraneous content in the post, along with something useful, and the extra stuff serves only to bother people, edit it out, leaving behind what is useful. You should not do this with suggested edits, so it becomes an option only when you have enough rep to edit without others needing to review your work. (There is a reject reason related to changing too much or going against the position of the original author.)

All these approaches reduce the amount of unpleasantness you see, in some cases immediately. They may also, in the long term, lead the user to behave differently. If you're a seasoned and experienced user of your site, you may wish to try accelerating that process with carefully chosen comments. However this should not be the first thing you try; I can tell you from years of experience and observation that commenting to tell people what they are doing wrong often backfires. As your first approach, just **make the site better** by editing, flagging, and voting. This really will improve your experience of the site.